# Do I have to widgetize my pages?

Tags: pages, widgets

I have a three pages. On front page I want to show some custom test about page1,link to page1, custom text about page2, link to page2, custom text about page3, link to page3.

And then I want a another page that includes texts from all three pages on one page-template.

Is the correct way then to make widgets of these three pages?

Comment: You can use any 1 sidebar for all three pages and with widget logic you can add condition where these widget should display.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/

Comment: If you already use Jetpack Plugin for Wordpress, you can use Widget Visibility feature for create conditional rules on widgets

Comment: I'm not using any plugins with widget-support. But my question is more about if I have to widgetize my pages in my scenario? I guess the answer is a simple yes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use page templates and template parts. On your *Front Page*, you include the Texts as Template Parts:

```
 Front Page
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|    Page A     |    Page B     |    Page C     |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  Link Page 1  |  Link Page 2  |  Link Page 3  |
| Text 1 (TP1*) | Text 2 (TP2*) | Text 3 (TP3*) |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Then you reuse them in your other (page) template:

```
 Other Page
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|                       Content                       |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Template Part 1 | Template Part 2 | Template Part 3 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

That's maybe easier than creating widget areas and fetching *static text* from the DB.